# object.style.height doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I've googled this but didn't find an answer, this is strange.  In Javascript in Firefox when I do object.style.height it doesn't return anything.  Would anybody know why?

In CSS I've put

```
#movable {
height: 100px;
....
```

In HTML I've put

```
<div id="movable">&nbsp;</div>
```

And in JS:

```
alert(movable.style.height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.style` is just a conversion of the element's `style` attribute into a scriptable object. If you haven't set any inline style on the element, you won't get anything back.

If you want to query the dimensions of an element, there are a number of ways, such as [`object.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect).

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to get the element's CSS height. If there isn't one defined in the element's style, that's what you get.

If you want the physical height, use `object.offsetHeight`